# could this be a fuse?

Tags: charger, fuses, smart

I was so stupid to leave a Ring rsc 516 smart charger in the rain. Hopefully, only the fuse is blown.
However, I am not sure where the fuse is?

could it be the black thing on the photo? 
[image]

I did a continuity test, but there was no beep.

Comment: Hello and welcome to eesx. Please, take a good picture from the top that includes a bigger portion of the board, we are interested in the small text on the board itself (like N and L next to where the mains wire arrive). What makes you think that that component is a fuse? Usually fuses are made of glass so that they can be readily inspected.

Comment: There are many clues it is a fuse, but we can't be sure of course. Usually the first thing on a PCB after mains wiring input is a fuse, so it fits that description. Also, it fits into description of a glass fuse inside black shrink wrap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! I placed a bigger photo on my webpage: http://garst.nl

Comment: And here is a photo of the pcb:
http://garst.nl/pcb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black thing could be a fuse within shrink wrap. However, fuses don't blow just because you left the device in the rain. Most likely rain damaged the circuitry and something else is blown, too much current passed via the fuse and it blew. If you don't fix the problem but only replace the fuse, it will blow too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like an unshielded inductor with shrink tube over it.

With sufficient current/voltage anything will act as a fuse or an arc lamp.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't look like that, but I think it looks somewhat like a fuse which would (in my experience) be far more common than a diff mode choke especially this close the line wire.

Comment: @OskarSkog It could be a glass fuse with shrink wrap over it. Maybe OP should peel back the shrink wrap and find out. Of course if  the fuse is blown there are probably other things that are fried.

Comment: I did what you suggested and indeed it was a blown fuse.